# How to customize specific page or list of posts on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to list specific information on a Wordpress page or category page, but I don't know how to do it, it's very simple information like [this](https://lacomunidad.com.py/buscar/?buscar=&categorias_base=30) page, I don't know if I need a plugin to do that or if I just need to modify the way wordpress list my posts of a specific category.

I need to understand better how can I modify things, because I'm new with Wordpress, I kno HTML, CSS, Javascript but I don't have those options.

I need 2 'pages' to save and list information like photo, email, name and another to list courses with information like title, date, description, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to take full control of your WordPress edit screens & custom field data.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/